# Temperature sensors not detected on AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D

Tags: drivers, temperature, amd-ryzen

I’ve recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a PC with an AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D and a ROG Strix B650E-E Gaming WiFi motherboard. I was trying to monitor the CPU temperature using lm-sensors, which does however not show any values related to the CPU:

```
nvme-pci-0900
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

amdgpu-pci-0c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      1000.00 mV 
vddnb:         1.02 V  
edge:         +38.0°C  
PPT:          23.19 W
```

I tried running sensors-detect, which was unable to detect additional sensors

In /sys/class/thermal/ there are also no thermal zones showing up.

My BIOS is able to display the temperature, so the sensors should be physically functional.

Am i missing any drivers here that need to be installed manually?

Comment: May be workaround in this issue will help you
https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/154

Comment: @obezyan After an OS update to Ubuntu 23.04 the sensors are now surprisingly detected by k10temp. Thanks for the response anyways.